# .htaccess RewriteRule blocked/ignored for .css and .js extension?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have switched servers and suddenly some of my .htaccess rules stopped working. One of them is the one bellow which redirects `/scripts.js` to my `/includes/load_js.php` file.

```
# NOT WORKING
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} scripts.js
RewriteRule . includes/load_js.php [L]
```

The strange part is that, if (for testing purposes only) I rename the rule from `scripts.js` into, lets say `scripts.tst` then is working, I can change the extension into anything except `.js` or `.css` and is working, otherwise for `.js` and `.css` I get 404 Not Found.

```
# WORKING BUT NOT NEEDED, I NEED .JS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} scripts.tst
RewriteRule . includes/load_js.php [L]
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: We’d need to see your full rewrite configuration, to be able to determine if any other rules might interfere.

Comment: FYI, you don’t need a RewriteCond to check against the URL _path_, the RewriteRule can match on that on its own.

Comment: Thanks for answering, for testing purposes I kept only that rule in the .htaccess file, so no other rules interfere. The only difference between servers is that the new server (where the rule is not working) is actually NGINX. Is it possible that it is configured to restrict JS/CSS/JPG rewrites? I have no previous experience with NGINX and have no idea if is recommended to mix it up with .htaccess but I have no access to nginx.conf file. So basically the rule works for ANY file extension, except .js/.css/,jpg that's why I would guess is some server restriction? Thanks!

Comment: Huh? NGINX doesn’t care for .htaccess files, as far as I know. If you installed any specific modules to make it actually use them, then you need to add that info to your question.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, the client just gave me FTP access and I have uploaded the files from the old server to the new server, I checked with `phpinfo()` and I see the server has: `Apache 2.0 Handler` installed and `Server API: FPM/FastCGI`. I guess I will have to contact the WebMaster for more clarification on this. Thank you for your help so far, I will be back and update my question when I find a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server was running both Nginx and Apache and there was some sort of conflict in serving files. While Apache using my .htaccess file was successfully honoring some of the redirects, others, on the other hand were "stolen" by NGINX (*.jpg, *.png, *.js, *.css) and this way the request never had the chance to even reach my .htaccess to process the redirect rules.

**TL;DR**: Server configuration: both Apache and NGINX == NO-NO, results in fighting over requests, nobody wins.

**"SOLUTION"** <- (*notice the quotes*): The WebMaster removed NGINX and only Apache remained standing, this way, processing my .htaccess and all rules working like on the previous server.